# Assets serving paths in Rails 3.1 - how to customize it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

I stumbled upon this problem: I want different type of assets to be served from the respective directories, not from `/assets`.

For example, if I create `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` I want it to be served from `/assets/javascripts/application.js`, not from `/assets/application.js`. Right now it serves from the latter location and I couldn't find any config option in the doc that changes this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[there is](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/337) a big discussion about it

Comment: I read it, I believe this discussion is about the convention of organizing source assets (scss, coffee etc) in the app/assets folder. No? What i'm talking about is compiling files using the same dir structure, for instance `app/assets/javascripts/` would render into `public/assets/javascripts` not `public/assets`.

Comment: yes, I agree with you, it sounds reasonable to keep the dir structure.

Comment: anyway, public assets can be combined and compressed files, like all.js in production mode. so public/assets can have only 2 files: all.js, all.css. is what Jammit do for now. what do you think?

Comment: since the css and js are all complied into single file, why is the directory structure necessary?

Comment: That's the thing, it's not always a good idea to compile all of the js (or css) in one huge file.

Comment: I trust [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). "80% of the end-user response time is spent on the front-end. Most of this time is tied up in downloading all the components in the page: images, stylesheets, scripts, Flash, etc. Reducing the number of components in turn reduces the number of HTTP requests required to render the page. This is the key to faster pages.
Combined files are a way to reduce the number of HTTP requests by combining all scripts into a single script, and similarly combining all CSS into a single stylesheet."